# Dashboard look and feel customization in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am using Pentaho communtiy edition. I am trying to customize my own dashboard look and feel.  I followed  "Creating a new dashboard look and feel" article to do so. When I run the dashboard, it shows an Unable to render dahboard error.Also when I followed the steps mentioned in the above link,I am not able to understand where to place the dashboard-custom.xcdf and template.html file

Comment: can you share which link are you talking about ?? i cannot find any link !!

Comment: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/Creating+a+new+dashboard+look+and+feel